# Partitioning the hard drive with only one device

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I currently run Ubuntu and I like it a lot, but I am unable to play any good games without using the Wine/PlayOnLinux or in a virtual machine.

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu, but I have only one 2TB hard drive. When I try to partition the drive, I get an error saying the drive is busy (which makes sense because I'm using it).

I tried to download the image of Windows and Ubuntu in separate USB drives and tried to boot from the BIOS, but it didn't work.

I think the easiest way would be to completely erase the entire hard drive and partition it into 2 1TB drives. From there I could reinstall Ubuntu and Windows separately.

Any suggestions on how to do this without using a CD?

This is the output of `lsblk` command:

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0   1.8T  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but can I suggest to download Gparted without the complete live CD (`Gparted live`) http://gparted.org/liveusb.php it might work.

Answer (score 1):

- Boot gparted live disk or Ubuntu live disk.
- Open gparted partition editor and shrink it's space to 1 TB.
- create a new ntfs partition(primary) for Windows from that 1 TB of free space.
- Install Windows on the created ntfs partition by chhosing custom option during Windows installation.
- And finally don't forget to run boot-repair.

Comment: I already tried using gparted. I got an error saying:

'The partition could not be unmounted from the following mount points:

/

Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points. You are advised to unmount them manually.'

Comment: post the output of `lsblk` command in your question.

Comment: i ask you to boot from Ubuntu live disk(aka installation disk)

Comment: @user274987, you can't run gparted from the hard disk since you are using the disk.  Hence why he said to boot from another disk.

Comment: I have tried to use 2 different usb drives to boot from the setup menu. One with the ubuntu ios image and one with the windows ios image. My computer doesn't read them.

How can I just erase my hard drive completely? I feel like then it will read the usb drive with ubuntu or windows and I will be able to partition it before I even install an operating system.

Comment: did you change the boot-order in bios to set USB as the first option?

Comment: Yes I did that. I get the same message from the computer. Something like "Reboot or install media into the selected boot drive and push any key". This runs as a loop and doesn't recognize the ios image inside the usb.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and I fixed it. I will explain step by step in the simplest way possible how to dual boot windows 7 on the ubuntu desktop with one hard drive and one usb drive.

1. Download the Ubuntu Iso Image of the desktop version from the ubuntu website.
2. Use the starter disk creator application to turn the iso image into a "CD" (Should be found in the dash). Save the "CD" into the USB drive. (This step is important because your computer will not recognize the iso image as a "bootable device")

*NOTE: The reason you need to download the ubuntu cd is because you need to run ubuntu through your USB to partition the hard drive. This is because you cannot partition a hard drive if you are using it.

1. Plug in the USB and restart your computer and run the boot menu, choose the USB and click the choice "Try Ubuntu". DO NOT install ubuntu. It might take a while to load the trial desktop but be patient.
2. Once you are on the desktop of the trial version your current hard drive is not in use anymore. At this point open the application "gparted" and resize your partitions as you please.

*NOTE: The partition must be compatible with Windows 7. There are two types of partition tables, GPT and MBR. You cannot download Windows 7 on a GPT. So you must make sure your partitions are "Master Boot Record", NOT GUID/GPT.

After the partition is done you can go back to your original desktop by restarting your computer.

1. Download the Windows 7 iso image from w7 forums or whenever you please.
2. Go to the Microsoft Website and follow their instructions to turn the iso image into a bootable "CD" on your USB stick. (You can use the same USB as long as you delete the ubuntu live CD).
3. Restart your computer with the USB drive connected and run the boot menu. Choose the USB device and you should be good to go!!!

This took me 2 days to figure out how to do but it was a good experience and I learned a lot. I hope this makes it easier for someone else! :)